# Move NSView around until it hits a border

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, draggable, nsview

In a Cocoa-based App i'm having a canvas for drawing, inherited from NSView, as well as a rectangle, also inherited from NSView. Dragging the rectangle around inside of the canvas is no problem:

```
-(void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
  NSPoint myOrigin = self.frame.origin;

  [self setFrameOrigin:NSMakePoint(myOrigin.x + [theEvent deltaX], 
                                   myOrigin.y - [theEvent deltaY])];
}
```

Works like a charm. The issue i'm having now: How can i prevent the rectangle from being moved outside the canvas?

So, first of all i would like to fix this just for the left border, adapting the other edges afterwards. My first idea is: "check whether the x-origin of the rectangle is negative". But: once it is negative the rectangle can't be moved anymore around (naturally). I solved this with moving the rectangle to zero x-offset in the else-branch. This works but it's ... ugly.

So i'm little puzzled with this one, any hints? Definitely the solution is really near and easy. That easy, that i cannot figure it out (as always with easy solutions ;).

Regards

Macs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest not using the `deltaX` and `deltaY`; try using the event's location in the *superview*. You'll need a reference to the subview.

```
// In the superview
- (void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)event {
    NSPoint mousePoint = [self convertPoint:[event locationInWindow] 
                             fromView:nil];

    // Could also add the width of the moving rectangle to this check 
    // to keep any part of it from going outside the superview
    mousePoint.x = MAX(0, MIN(mousePoint.x, self.bounds.size.width));
    mousePoint.y = MAX(0, MIN(mousePoint.y, self.bounds.size.height));

    // position is a custom ivar that indicates the center of the object;
    // you could also use frame.origin, but it looks nicer if objects are 
    // dragged from their centers
    myMovingRectangle.position = mousePoint;
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

You'd do essentially the same bounds checking in `mouseUp:`.

**UPDATE:** You should also have a look at the View Programming Guide, which walks you through creating a draggable view: [Creating a Custom View](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/SubclassingNSView/SubclassingNSView.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH7-SW4).

---

Sample code that should be helpful, though not strictly relevant to your original question:

In DotView.m:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    // Ignoring dirtyRect for simplicity
    [[NSColor colorWithDeviceRed:0.85 green:0.8 blue:0.8 alpha:1] set];
    NSRectFill([self bounds]);
    // Dot is the custom shape class that can draw itself; see below
    // dots is an NSMutableArray containing the shapes
    for (Dot *dot in dots) {
        [dot draw];
    }
}

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {
    NSPoint mousePoint = [self convertPoint:[event locationInWindow] 
                             fromView:nil];

    currMovingDot = [self clickedDotForPoint:mousePoint];
    // Move the dot to the point to indicate that the user has
    // successfully "grabbed" it    
    if( currMovingDot ) currMovingDot.position = mousePoint;
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

// -mouseDragged: already defined earlier in post

- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)event {
    if( !currMovingDot ) return;

    NSPoint mousePoint = [self convertPoint:[event locationInWindow] 
                             fromView:nil];
    spot.x = MAX(0, MIN(mousePoint.x, self.bounds.size.width));
    spot.y = MAX(0, MIN(mousePoint.y, self.bounds.size.height));

    currMovingDot.position = mousePoint;
    currMovingDot = nil;
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

- (Dot *)clickedDotForPoint:(NSPoint)point {
    // DOT_NUCLEUS_RADIUS is the size of the 
    // dot's internal "handle"
    for( Dot *dot in dots ){
        if( (abs(dot.position.x - point.x) <= DOT_NUCLEUS_RADIUS) &&
            (abs(dot.position.y - point.y) <= DOT_NUCLEUS_RADIUS)) {
            return dot;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Dot.h

```
#define DOT_NUCLEUS_RADIUS (5)

@interface Dot : NSObject {
    NSPoint position;
}

@property (assign) NSPoint position;

- (void)draw;

@end
```

Dot.m

```
#import "Dot.h"

@implementation Dot

@synthesize position;

- (void)draw {
    //!!!: Demo only: assume that focus is locked on a view.
    NSColor *clr = [NSColor colorWithDeviceRed:0.3 
                                         green:0.2 
                                          blue:0.8 
                                         alpha:1];
    // Draw a nice border
    NSBezierPath *outerCirc;
    outerCirc = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:
                         NSMakeRect(position.x - 23, position.y - 23, 46, 46)];
    [clr set];
    [outerCirc stroke];
    [[clr colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7] set];
    [outerCirc fill];
    [clr set];
    // Draw the "handle"
    NSRect nucleusRect = NSMakeRect(position.x - DOT_NUCLEUS_RADIUS,
                                    position.y - DOT_NUCLEUS_RADIUS,
                                    DOT_NUCLEUS_RADIUS * 2,
                                    DOT_NUCLEUS_RADIUS * 2);
    [[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:nucleusRect] fill];
}

@end
```

As you can see, the `Dot` class is very lightweight, and uses bezier paths to draw. The superview can handle the user interaction.

Comment: Hm, ok ... so two more questions to this: (1) Why shouldn't i use the deltas? (2) When using the superview, then i'll always have to check if i'm dragging the rectangle, i. e. if my mouse is above the rectangle. If i'm having multiple rectangles this seems quite inefficient to me, or did i misunderstood something?

Comment: @macs: the reason you shouldn't use the deltas is that doing so results in the problem you're facing! As for the second question, I actually almost suggested that you may want to reconsider the rectangle being an `NSView` subclass. If you just have the one, it's simple for the superview to do the drawing. If you're planning on having many, then performance becomes an issue; see [Optimizing View Drawing](http://goo.gl/nEVcL).

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation. I'm going to implement your suggestions.

Comment: @macs: If you're planning on having a lot of rectangles, then someone's going to have to do hit tests, either you or AppKit. Keeping an array of `NSRects` makes it easy to figure out which one the user wants to move.

Comment: @Josh: In the end the application will have multiple shapes. Since i'm new to Objective-C the first thing i wanted to figure out is the best way to draw shapes and how to drag them around and so on. As the programming guide suggests: Having a lot of views isn't really efficient, so i'm going to replace them by a lightweight custom class afterwards.

Comment: @Josh: Well, i'm also going to read the "Cocoa Drawing Guide" first. Using lots of views is indeed a bad idea, but was the first idea coming into my mind.

Comment: @macs: that's the way I've done it in the past. Note that your custom class _can_ still draw itself; you just have to be sure that drawing code is never called except when there is a [Graphics Context](http://goo.gl/jaqD9) set up for you, such as when you are inside your superview's `drawRect:`. I'll add some more sample code which isn't strictly relevant to your question but should be helpful.

Comment: @Josh: Thank you very much for those suggestions, i'll appreciate them.

Comment: @macs: Code added; glad I can help! Good luck.

Comment: @macs: just a note to say that I noticed a big typo in the `mouseDown` that I pasted here; `currMovingDot` should have been set not to `mousePoint` but `[self clickedDotForPoint:mousePoint];` Probably you had already figured that out, though!

Comment: @Josh: Tested it, works like a charm, thank you again :) Next step: Implementing more shapes ;)